# Service inheritance with Angular 1.x and ES6

Tags: javascript, angularjs, inheritance, ecmascript-6, es6-class

I am using Angular 1.6 with ES6. Until now I implemented inheritence with the `extend` keyword on ES6 classes

```
export default class myChildService extends myBaseService {
    constructor(someDependency){
         'ngInject'
         super();

         someDependency.doStuff();
    }
}
```

and registered the child-class as angular-service

```
import myChildService from ./myChildService

angular.module('myApp', [])
    .service('myChildService', myChildService)
```

This works well so far!

However I would like to split my application into smaller modules. This means I will have several different angular-modules which will need access to `myBaseService` in order to inherit the functionality.

I could just `import` the file containing `myBaseService`, but this seems not very angulary. It basically means I disregard angular-modules and DI everytime I use inheritance.

**Question:**

Is there any way to export an ES6-class from an angular-module `base` so that I can reuse it on an angular-module `child` which depends on `base`?

Maybe I am just looking at this the wrong way - if you have other suggestions to implement inheritance of angular-services/ factories **using ES6-classes**, please go ahead.

Comment: I'd say you have to `import` `myBaseService` in all places you want to `extend` it.

Comment: I guess - it just doesn't feel right to mix angular-modules and es6-modules. At least I didn't see any other angular-library which exposes an angular-module as well as some plain es6-classes.

Comment: _"it just doesn't feel right to mix angular-modules and es6-modules"_ They are completely unrelated.  It's not one or the other.

Comment: I agree with @Arg0n solution.

Answer (score 0):

Why importing is not angulary? If you would like to use base service functionality, the module should know it's definition.